# Invalidate NSTimer from other ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, timer, nstimer

In my project there are 3 View Controllers where 
1vc have list of all products and its closing date, 
2vc will show product detail with count down timer, and have 1 button there to bid on that Item,
3VC will display bid amount and all other detail with bid button.

So it works like VC1 => VC2 => VC3.

So from VC3 I go back to VC2, it should run timer (it should run in background when VC2 is in background).

But when I go to VC1 to VC2, I need to remove timer from background and set new timer with new count down of another product..
I added NSTimer like this

```
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

IN VC2, I have

```
{
    NSTimer *timer;
}

- (void)updateCounter:(NSTimer *)theTimer {
    if(secondsLeft > 0 ){
        secondsLeft -- ;

        days = (secondsLeft / 3600) / 24;
        int reminder = secondsLeft % 84600;
        hours = (reminder / 3600);
        reminder = (reminder % 3600);
        minutes = (reminder) / 60;
        reminder = reminder % 60;
        seconds = reminder;

        self.headerTimeLastCallLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", hours];
        self.headerTimeHourLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", minutes];
        self.headerTimeMinutesLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", seconds];

        if ([[[self.auctionItemDetail objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"daysLeft"] integerValue] == 0) {
            self.headerTimeLastCallLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Hours", hours];
            self.headerTimeHourLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Minutes", minutes];
            self.headerTimeMinutesLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Seconds", seconds];
        }else{ 
            self.headerTimeLastCallLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Days", days];
            self.headerTimeHourLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Hours", hours];
            self.headerTimeMinutesLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Minutes", minutes];
        }
    }
}

-(void)countdownTimer{

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(updateCounter:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];

}
```

I have added removal code in `viewDidLoad` like this

```
@try {
        [timer invalidate];
        NSLog(@"Timer invalidated");
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Timer invalidated with exception");
    }
    @finally {

    }
```

But still timer is running in background.. So when I visit VC2 second time, there will be 2 timer running in background(Because every time I visit VC2 timer will be added in mainRunLoop).. There I want to remove 1st Timer..

> **Edited**

I have added timer to singleton class,

```
Constant.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Constant : NSObject
{}
+ (NSTimer *) aucNSTimer;

@end
```

.

```
Constant.m

#import "Constant.h"

@implementation Constant
+ (NSTimer *) aucNSTimer
{
    static NSTimer *timer = nil;
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (timer == nil)
            timer = [[NSTimer alloc] init];
    }
    return timer;
}
@end
```

.

```
VC2.h
{
    NSTimer *timer;
}
```

.
VC2.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
timer = [Constant aucNSTimer];
@try {
        [[Constant aucNSTimer] invalidate];
        [timer invalidate];
        NSLog(@"Timer invalidated");
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Timer invalidated with exception");
    }
    @finally {

    }
}
```

Comment: Just remove `[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];` because `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` set timer with loop if you set `repeats:YES`.

Answer (score 0):

No Need to add timer in mainRunLoop

```
-(void)countdownTimer
{
  timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(updateCounter:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

And if you want to Invalid timer then plz follow this code:

```
if (timer)
{
   [timer invalidate];
   timer = nil;
}
```

And implement this code in **dealloc** method also

```
-(void)dealloc
{
  if (timer)
   {
    [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;
   }
}
```

Don't write `[super dealloc];` if you are enable ARC in your code.